# Parent's state params empty on $urlRouterProvider.otherwise state reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have my state configurations defined as below:

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('parentState', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/:tenantId/',
        param: {
          tenantId: {
            array: false
          }
        },
        views: {
          'header@': {
            templateUrl: 'home/header.html',
            controller: 'Header as vm'
          },
          'footer@': {
            templateUrl: 'home/footer.html',
            controller: 'FooterCtrl as vm'
          }
        },
        resolve: userResolve,
        data: {
          private: true
        }
      })
      //...4-5 other child states, then a state to handle unknown urls
      .state('parentState.otherwise', {
        views: {
          '@': {
            templateUrl: 'home/404/pageNotFound.html',
            controller: 'PageNotFoundCtrl as vm'
          }
        }
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
      $injector.get('$state').go('parentState.otherwise', {}, {
        location: false
      });
    });
```

Now, when an invalid URL is entered, `parentState.otherwise` state loads correctly, and `parentState` param, i.e. tenantId, is also correctly filled.
However, on page reload(refresh, Ctrl + R) with same invalid URL, `parentState.otherwise` state loads, but the problem is `parentState` param, i.e. tenantId is coming as empty string("").

Comment: note: `param:` should be `params:`

Comment: tried, but didn't change anything. behaviour was same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, with `location: false`, the parent state, i.e. `parentState` in this case, was not picking up `tenantId` param from the URL on page refresh. So, if we explicitly pass `tenantId` param to child state, i.e. `parentState.otherwise` while opening it, everything works perfectly even on page refresh:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
  $injector.get('$state').go('parentState.otherwise', {
    tenantId: 'someTenantId'
  }, {
    location: false
  });
});
```